# Gradle and nested extensions

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to achieve the following dsl as a Gradle Plugin :

```
plugin {
   pluginA {
      property1 ""
      property2 ""
   }
   pluginB {
      property3 ""
   }
}
```

pluginA and pluginB are nothing alike, I don't want to use a NamedDomainObjectContainer.
With the previous dsl everything was ok :

```
pluginA {
   property1 ""
   property2 ""
}
pluginB {
   property3 ""
}

project.pluginA.extensions.create('pluginA', PluginAExtension)
project.pluginB.extensions.create('pluginB', PluginBExtension)
```

And I could check if the user has defined those extensions :

```
if(project.pluginA != null) {
    //Configure task
}
```

But since a use my main plugin, if I declare the sub-extensions like that :

```
project.extensions.create("plugin", PluginExtension)
project.plugin.extensions.create('pluginA', PluginAExtension)
project.plugin.extensions.create('pluginB', PluginBExtension)
```

If the user does that :

```
project {

}
```

`if(project.plugin.pluginA != null)` returns true

I tried without the plugin.extensions.create(), and use directly in extensions class :

```
class PluginExtension {
    PluginAExtension pluginA
    PluginBExtension pluginB
}
```

but now I get pluginA() == null always. I now I can declare everything as properties with closure but that's a lot of works for something that was working before. I just want to add an enclosing plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
import org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil;

class PluginExtension {
    PluginAExtension pluginA
    ...

    PluginAExtension pluginA(Closure closure) {
        return pluginA(ConfigureUtil.configureUsing(closure))
    }

    void pluginA(Action<? super PluginAExtension> action) {
        if (pluginA == null) pluginA = new PluginAExtension()
        action.execute(pluginA)
    }

    ...
}
```

See [DefaultProject.copySpec(Closure)](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java#L891) for similar functionality

Comment: Actually I was wrong on something :
if(project.plugin != null) is always true when I do project.extensions.create("plugin", PluginExtension)

Is there any way to check if the user as defined a plugin {} block in the build.gradle ??

Comment: Using my example code, you can check `if(plugin.pluginA == null)`

Comment: Not much difference apart from adding "public" to the class and methods and adding a getter for `pluginA`